# fastify.js equivalent of express next() for Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fastify, fastify-multipart

In express, we have routes like so :-

```
app.get("/route1", function(req, res, next){
...
}
```

What would be the equivalent statement in [Fastify Framework](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Routes/) (next part is important)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent would be:

```js
app.get('/route1', function(request, reply) {
...
}
```

Where [`request`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Request/) and [`reply`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/) are the Fastify custom object.

There is NOT `next` since there is no a chain of middleware in Fastify, but there is the concept of [Lifecycle of a request](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Lifecycle/#lifecycle/) that you can customize with [hooks](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/)

Comment: done - comment requires a min char length